# sudo escalation password fails - /etc/shadow hash ok, group ok, /etc/sudoers ok

Tags: security, sudo, authorization

After system update/upgrade, I cannot escalate with sudo using correct password:

```
user $ sudo -s
[sudo] password for user: ********************
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for user: ********************
Sorry, try again.
```

(It is a VPS, and login is done via *ssh* without password - password is only needed for *sudo*)

Group is set correctly.

```
$ groups user
user : user sudo docker
```

This line is in */etc/sudoers* :

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

In rescue mode, reset the password, double checked the contents of */etc/shadow* against an independent program:

```
mkpasswd --method=sha-512 --salt=GiHwtvMC
Password: ********************
$6$GiHwtvMC$pONfZo5...<omitted>...Vg5c0
```

The output matches exactly the hash shown in */etc/shadow*.  Still *sudo* escalation fails.

**Are there other system settings that could prevent *sudo* escalation with a correct password?**

(It occurred to me that the upgrade could have contained a targeted deliberate hack to persuade me to allow *sudo* escalation without a password, but that seems most unlikely).

---

Contents of */etc/sudoers* , comments removed

```
Defaults        env_reset,timestamp_timeout=-1
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:"
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

---

*excerpt from /var/log/auth.log*

```
Jan 31 10:46:48 izu sshd[1126]: Accepted publickey for username from 111.111.111.11 port 52768 ssh2: RSA SHA256:<omitted>
Jan 31 10:46:48 izu sshd[1126]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user username by (uid=0)
Jan 31 10:46:48 izu systemd-logind[679]: New session 1 of user username.
Jan 31 10:46:48 izu systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user username by (uid=0)
Jan 31 10:46:48 izu sshd[1126]: User child is on pid 1150
Jan 31 10:46:48 izu sshd[1150]: Starting session: shell on pts/0 for username from 111.111.111.11 port 52768 id 0
Jan 31 10:47:16 izu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=username uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/0 ruser=username rhost=  user=username
```

---

The problem was in a previously working modification to */etc/pam.d/common-auth* enabling logfile excerpts to be sent by email.

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure

# ADDED HOOK NOW REMOVED
auth    optional  pam_exec.so seteuid /etc/local/lib/pam_auth_fail_notify.sh    

# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

Comment: Is rootpw or targetpw set in sudoers?

Comment: @JeffSchaller - neither is in sudoers - I added sudoers content listing for your perusal.  The prompt  *[sudo] password for user:*  seems to indicate the default is for the users password.  I also set and tried root password, but that didn't work.

Comment: Anything in syslog, `/var/log/secure` or equivalent ?  I guess you may need to boot into rescue mode to retrieve it....

Comment: All looking clean there.  My money would be on the upgrade having borked some pam settings in `/etc/pam.d`.

Comment: @steve - added.

Comment: I agree with @steve `/etc/pam.d/sudo` is your next step.  Also double check the file system and make sure that `/usr/bin/sudo` is set with owner root, group root permissions `-rwsr-xr-x`

Comment: @JeffSchaller - It turns out that a change I made long ago to /etc/pam/common-auth , which sent mail with a grep'd excerpt from the log file in case of bad login/sudo, was incompatible after the update. It still sent mail, but every login/sudo was bad. After restoring the original version, it is now functioning correctly.

Comment: @steve - It turns out that a change I made long ago to /etc/pam/common-auth , which sent mail with a grep'd excerpt from the log file in case of bad login/sudo, was incompatible after the update. It still sent mail, but every login/sudo was bad. After restoring the original version, it is now functioning correctly.

Comment: Splendid, thanks for following up with reply.  Probably worth making your final comment an answer, so this question gets marked as fully answered now.

Answer (score 1):

The advice from @steve about the problem being in */etc/pam.d* was correct.

The problem was in a previously working modification to /etc/pam.d/common-auth enabling logfile excerpts to be sent by email.

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure

# ADDED HOOK NOW REMOVED
auth    optional  pam_exec.so seteuid /etc/local/lib/pam_auth_fail_notify.sh    

# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

AFIR, that file and others in */etc/pam.d* contains sequential instructions which push return values onto a stack - it's not simple to understand and it's fragile, and apparently sensitive to updates.

The point of putting the modification there was to capture both *sudo* and *login* (and *ssh* key login?) failures at one point.  It was something I saw on Stack Exchange somewhere ... Now I will implement each of those functions separately in orthodox ways.  Bad *sudo*s are easy - I only had to have these two lines in */etc/sudoers*

```
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    mailerpath="/usr/local/sbin/sendmail"
```

In my case this *sendmail* is not standard - it sends via an API to a free mail service.  An orthodox mail setup wouldn't require that line.

Comment: The instructions @CraigHicks followed to setup email sending upon bad login attempts is described in https://askubuntu.com/a/729841/21195 by me. I'm not sure what caused this behavior but  your `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` is set with `success=1` where it should be `success=2`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the pam setup was most likely due to the new way Ubuntu builds pam - [success=1 default=ignore].

If pam_unix succeeds, skip 1 line.  It was expecting to skip pam_deny, but instead, it skipped your pam_exec, and then executed pam_deny.  If you had moved pam_exec between pam_deny and pam_succeed, it probably would have worked as expected.

Comment: I misread the thread. I thought you were alerting on success, not failure.  In that case, the correct answer was to change pam_unix to success=2 (skip two lines if pam_unix succeeds).  If pam_unix fails, run the alert script and run pam_deny.  If pam_unix succeeds, skip both pam_exec and pam_deny, and execute pam_permit.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. If you want to improve on your answer, please edit it rather than posting additional information as comment. Reading the comment section is cumbersome, and comments are subject to removal without notice.